# Inner joins with have clause does not give output

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, inner-join, having

I have tables like this.

PollingDivision

```
       pdID pdName
         1    Homagama
         2    Maharagama
         3    Kesbewa
```

PollingBooth

```
       PBID   PBName  pdivID
        1      HP      1
        2      HD      2
```

PollingBoothElection

```
       pbID   elecID numofEO
        1         1      3
```

PollingBoothElectionOfficial

```
      pbID elecid eOfficialID
        1     1       1
```

I'm trying to get pooling booth names from polling booth in which the allocated election official count(count of eOfficialID column for a particular elecID and pbID in PollingBoothElectionOfficial table) is less than the number of election official number in PollingBoothElection Table by Polling Division.

Here's what I tried.

```
SELECT 
    PB.PBName, COUNT(PBEO.eOfficialID) AS EOCount
FROM 
    PollingBoothElection PBE
INNER JOIN 
    PollingBooth PB ON PBE.pbID = PB.PBID
INNER JOIN 
    PollingDivision PD ON PB.pdivID = PD.pdID
INNER JOIN 
    PollingBoothElectionOfficial PBEO ON PBE.elecID = PBEO.elecID 
                                      AND PBE.pbID = PBEO.pboothID
WHERE 
    PBE.elecID = 1 
    AND PD.pdName = 'Homagama'
GROUP BY 
    PB.PBName, PBE.numOfEO
HAVING 
    COUNT(PBEO.eOfficialID) < (PBE.numOfEO);
```

Though I have data in my table it does not give me a result. What am I doing wrong here?

Expected result

```
         pbName Count
          HP      1
```

Because For Polling Booth HP number of eo is 3 but in PollingBoothElectionOfficial table there's only 1 record for pbid1 elecid 1 so the count is less than the number of eos(numOfEO).

Comment: Can you post your expected result?

Comment: Your query is returning that.

Comment: I put the test as an answer. Kindly check.

Answer (score 0):

*I'll put it in here since I'll go beyond the comment limit.*

Your query results what you're expecting:

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
CREATE TABLE PollingDivision(
    pdID    INT,
    pdName  VARCHAR(20)
)
CREATE TABLE PollingBooth(
    PBID    INT,
    PBName  VARCHAR(20),
    pdivID  INT
)
CREATE TABLE PollingBoothElection(
    pbID    INT,
    elecID  INT,
    numofEO INT
)
CREATE TABLE PollingBoothElectionOfficial(
    pbID        INT,
    electID     INT,
    eOfficialID INT
)
INSERT INTO PollingDivision VALUES (1, 'Homagama'), (2, 'Maharagama'), (3, 'Kesbewa');
INSERT INTO PollingBooth VALUES (1, 'HP', 1), (2, 'HD', 2);
INSERT INTO PollingBoothElection VALUES (1, 1, 3);
INSERT INTO PollingBoothElectionOfficial VALUES (1, 1, 1);
```

**Your (formatted) query:**

```
SELECT 
    PB.PBName,
    COUNT(PBEO.eOfficialID) AS EOCount
FROM PollingBoothElection PBE
INNER JOIN PollingBooth PB
    ON PBE.pbID = PB.PBID
INNER JOIN PollingDivision PD
    ON PB.pdivID = PD.pdID
INNER JOIN PollingBoothElectionOfficial PBEO
    ON PBE.elecID = PBEO.electID --replaced PBEO.elecID with PBEO.electID
    AND PBE.pbID = PBEO.pbID -- replaced PBEO.pboothID with PBEO.pbID
WHERE 
    PBE.elecID = 1
    AND PD.pdName = 'Homagama'
GROUP BY PB.PBName, PBE.numOfEO
HAVING COUNT(PBEO.eOfficialID) < (PBE.numOfEO);
```

**RESULT**

```
PBName               EOCount
-------------------- -----------
HP                   1
```

Comment: my pollingBoothElectionOfficial table is almost empty but the query does not select any plling booth in PollingBoothElection with elecid 1? What do you think the cause is?

Comment: What do you mean? I just showed you that your query is returning your expect result.

Comment: Could you provide more details? Like table definitions and your original query? Note that your sample data and query do not have matching column names.

Answer (score 0):

This should help resulting to what you needed:

```
Select PBName, SUM(eOfficialIDCount)[Count]
from (Select pbID, elecID, Count(Distinct eOfficialID)eOfficialIDCount 
        from PollingBoothElectionOfficial Group by pbID, electID)A
Left Join (Select pbID, elecID, numofEO from PollingBoothElection)B On B.pbID+b.elecID = A.pbID+a.elecID
Left Join (Select pbID, PBName from PollingBooth)C On C.pbID = A.pbID
Where eOfficialIDCount < numofEO Group by PBName
```